# How to differentiate MAC addresses of Android devices and Laptops connected to a network?

Tags: android, networking, ip

I have a list of IPs and MAC addresses of connected devices. I need to restrict androids.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Every manufacturer has a different beginning to their mac addresses. If most of the laptops are of a certain brand, you can use that identifier to figure this out.